# How to expand hyphenated numbers from a file into a range of numbers?

Tags: python

I have a text file formatted like so

```
1-8
10-12
14-45
48-50
```

How do I go about getting the range of each line?

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8
10, 11, 12
```

I've tried splitting the file to get each number into a list. 1, 8, 10, 12, 14, 45, 48, 50, but I'm not sure how to translate that into the start and end numbers for range.

```
data = []
with open('file.txt','r') as myfile:
    for line in myfile:
        data.extend(map(int, line.split('-')))
print (data)
```

Comment: You are almost there.  If it's safe to assume that you will always have a pair of numbers, you can then loop over the list of numbers two at a time right?  Then you could do something like this `for i in range(num_1, num_2): #print your stuff here`.  There are other more pythonic sexy ways of doing this but for your case it's a good starting point I think.  If it won't always be a pair of numbers, so like `1-8, 10-12, 50`, it gets a bit more tricky.  But try to take this and run with it and see where you get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a short list comprehension to extract the numbers from a given line. Since the ranges you listed seem to be inclusive on both ends, we need to add one to end interval (j) below.

```
for line in myfile:
    i, j = [int(n) for n in line.split("-")]
    for x in range(i, j + 1):
        # do things
```

If you simply want to stick the two numbers in a range, here's an alternative:

```
range(*[int(n) for n in line.split("-")])
```

If you want to list out the numbers in the range, you need to wrap the expression in a `list()`.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to extract the start and end index from each line and use it in `range` to create your list

```
data = []

with open('file.txt','r') as myfile:
    for line in myfile:
        start,end = [int(item) for item in line.split('-')]
        li = list(range(start ,end+1))
        data.append(li)
print(data)
```

So if the input is:

```
1-8
10-12
14-45
48-50
```

The output will be:

```
[
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], 
[10, 11, 12], 
[14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45], 
[48, 49, 50]
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You're very close, you just need to append the list [`range()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range):

```
data = []
with open("file.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        start, end = map(int, line.split("-"))
        data.append(list(range(start, end + 1)))

print(data)
# [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], [10, 11, 12], [14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45], [48, 49, 50]]
```

And also making sure the `end` is incremented by one because it is not inclusive in `range()`.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to print the ranges, you can use this:

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as myfile:
    for line in myfile:
        nums = [int(i) for i in line.split('-')]
        nums[1] += 1  # more on this in a second
        my_range = range(*nums)  # the * unpacks the two numbers into two arguments
        print([i for i in my_range])
        # [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Walking through it, the first line in the `for` loop you pretty much have already. This just grabs the two numbers and interprets them as integers. After this line, `nums = [1, 8]` for your first line `'1-8'`. Next we add one to the the last element of the list, so `nums = [1, 9]` now. We do this because the `range(a, b)` builtin generates numbers from `a` to `b-1`.

Next we create a range that will generate the numbers that you want with `range(*nums)`. The `*` in that statement unpacks the list into the two arguments that `range()` is expecting.

Finally we print all of the items in the range. Since `my_range` is now a generator, we need to unpack it to print, so we use a list comprehension to iterate over it and get all of the numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you can match the pattern using [capturing groups](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) using Regex and add it into your list.

Regex: https://regex101.com/r/f1Ghff/1

```
(\d+)\-(\d+)
```

Explanation:

```
1st Capturing Group (\d+)
\d+ matches a digit (equal to [0-9])
+ Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
\- matches the character - literally (case sensitive)
2nd Capturing Group (\d+)
\d+ matches a digit (equal to [0-9])
+ Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
```

The code:

```
import re

str = """
1-8 
10-12 
14-45 
48-50
"""

pattern = r"(\d+)\-(\d+)"
matches = re.findall(pattern, str)

ranges = []

# Convert Group1 and Group2 into integers
for tuple in matches:
    low = int(tuple[0])
    high = int(tuple[1])
    ranges.append(list(range(low, high)))

print (ranges)
```

Outputting:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [10, 11], [14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44], [48, 49]]
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

Of course, it has no error checking, so you'd want to be mindful of the quality of your input data.

```
data = []
with open('file.txt','r') as myfile:
    for line in myfile:
        # Split the line and force conversion to int
        start_int, end_int = map(int, line.split('-'))
        # Get a Python 3 range - note this is not a list but a "range" type in Python 3, so we'll have to convert it before appending to our global list
        int_range = range(start_int, end_int+1)
        data.append(list(int_range))
```